# Never render a layout in response to xhrs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Most of the time I don't want to render a layout when the request comes from AJAX. To this end I've been writing `render :layout => !request.xhr?` frequently in my controller actions.

How can I make this the *default*? I.e., I'd like to be able to write

```
def new
  Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

and have the functionality be

```
def show
  Post.find(params[:id])
  render :layout => !request.xhr?
end
```

(I'm fine manually specifying a layout in the rare cases in which I want to use one.)

Comment: Can't just have AJAX calls use different URLs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout proc {|controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to make it the default to *never* render a layout for any XHR request, you can do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout proc { false if request.xhr? }
end
```

When the request is an XHR request, it renders the requested view without a layout. Otherwise, it uses the default layout behaviour, which looks up the layout by inheritance.

This is different than saying `controller.request.xhr? ? false : 'application'`, since that will *always* render the `application` layout for a non-XHR request, which effectively disables the lookup by inheritance.

Also see the [ActionView documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html#module-ActionView::Layouts-label-Inheritance+Examples) for the `nil` argument and layout inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

A normal after_filter won't work because we want to modify rendering.

How about hijacking render?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private
  def render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block) 
    options = {:layout => !request.xhr?}.merge(options) unless options.nil?
    super(options, extra_options)      
  end
end
```

Set the layout when calling render to override it.  A bit ugly but should work.

Comment: This won't work -- it just calls `render` immediately (before my controller has the opportunity to set up the environment for my view)

Comment: Of course, filters won't work here... my bad!  Does the updated solution do the trick?