# Rails prevent layout during AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched around and have not been able to find a solution for this type of mechanic.  I want to load all pages normally in Rails, but whenever I do an ajax request I just want to return the page without the layout.  So anytime I make an ajax requst I can append a `?page=true` or something along those lines and have Rails just return the page without the layout.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way to do it that I am missing?

Thanks for any help!

**Final Solution Working Code:**

In the controller all you need to do is append a little logic to the `format.html` in the `respond_to` block.

In the `show` method for example

```
def show
    # code beforehand

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :layout => !request.xhr? }
        # other formats
    end
end
```

And that's it!  Prevent layouts during AJAX requests!

**Note:** Thanks to the smathy's comment on his answer this was simplified further.  I originally had `format.html { render :layout => nil if request.xhr? }`  This solution works just as well, but smathy's modification keeps it even simpler.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in the application controller for every ajax request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Never render a layout in response to xhrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444866/never-render-a-layout-in-response-to-xhrs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to add that parameter, `request.xhr?` will return true in your controller when it's an Ajax request.  Just use that to decide whether to render the layout or not.

Comment: How would that work? I tried `if request.xhr? render :layout => nil end` in the show controller.  It is returning an error.  Either I am not using request.xhr? correctly or I am trying to remove the layout incorrectly.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, THANK you for the info.  I will edit the question with my actual final working code.  Thanks to your information, my solution is very "Rails Like" and I am extremely happy with it!

Comment: Nice solution, yes.  An alternative is to use the boolean itself - but negated.  Eg. I would do: `render :layout => !request.xhr?`