# Render a partial everytime on ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to run these three lines of code everytime when an ajax calls is made to an action in ruby on rails via ajax..

```
$('#mixpanel-tracking-page-view').attr('data-name', "<%= @analytics_event[:name] %>");
$('#mixpanel-tracking-page-view').attr('data-properties', "<%= @analytics_event[:properties].to_json.html_safe %>");
trackPageLoadEvents();
```

Right now I am writing these lines in every .js.erb file. I don't want to do that. Thats a third class way to handle the problem.

Can anyone guide me. For html request I have added in layout. What about ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it like this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a[rel*=your_ref]", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // Ajax call here
})
```

This will allow you to create links like this:

```
<%= link_to "your link", link_path, rel: "your_ref" %>
```

This means when you call these links (I.E you want to send a particular type of Ajax request), you'll be able to use standard functionality contained within that code

--

**Layout**

It's interesting you call it a "partial" - you'd be better rendering an `action` without any layout - this way, you're able to call any route in your app, and receive the pure `HTML` back in the response:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :select_layout

    private

    def select_layout
       false if request.xhr?
    end
end
```

We found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286875/rails-prevent-layout-during-ajax-request)

--

**Ajax:Success**

In reference to `Max Al Farakh`'s answer, you need to be careful with `ajaxSuccess`, as it's a *global* function:

> Whenever an Ajax request completes successfully, jQuery triggers the
>   ajaxSuccess event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with
>   the .ajaxSuccess() method are executed at this time.

In reference to your query directly, you'll want to emit any `ERB` code from your naked `js` code. The `erb` code works well in the `/views` folder, but the `asset_pipeline` can be loaded statically, meaning your `ERB` code will not render as expected.

The better way to do this is to pass the data back in your `response`, although defining this when you're sending HTML can be slightly tricky.

--

**Pusher**

If you adopted the strategy of accepting ajax responses without a layout, **I would use [`Pusher`](http://pusher.com)** to create a secondary stream of data, which I'll be able to update the page when a successful call is made:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   after_filter :send_analytics, only: :your_action

   def your_action
      #... stuff here
   end

   protected

   def send_analytics
      @analytics_event = ?
      Pusher['channel'].trigger('analytics_update', { name: "@analytics_event[:name]", event: "@analytics_event[:event]" })
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
pusher = new Pusher("****",cluster: 'eu')

channel = pusher.subscribe("analytics_update")
channel.bind("multi_destroy", function(analytics){
   alert analytics.name
});
```

This will allow you to call any Ajax request you wish, whilst updating the analytics information asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

There is a global [AjaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) callback. It will execute on every successful Ajax call. You need to add this in your layout:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('#mixpanel-tracking-page-view').attr('data-name', "<%= @analytics_event[:name] %>");
  $('#mixpanel-tracking-page-view').attr('data-properties', "<%=       @analytics_event[:properties].to_json.html_safe %>");
  trackPageLoadEvents();
});
```

If you only need to execute it when a call to a specific action is being made, you can check the URL like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "controller/action" ) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: This way changes to `@analytics_event` won't be captured, right?

Comment: Changes to analytics_event will not be reflected and that what exactly I need :(

Comment: Writing an answer about this. Don't know why this has so many upvotes, I had to downvote because some people may be confused

Comment: @RichPeck that what I am thinking. Why people are voting it so much as its not a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, looks like I misunderstood the question.